# Crittercism API Crash Trends Data For Custom Time Period

Tags: java, android, api, crittercism, apiclient

My primary need is to get DAU, MAU, Crash percent, Availability, Rating etc., for any custom time period. (Eg: last 2days, 1week, Date1 - Date2 etc.,) So far I have been using the data from Crash Trends page in dashboard, by setting custom date values and getting the data/values manually.

So, I wanted to automate this, and started implementing the Rest API. The documentation seemed pretty vague, and I only found the endpoint "apps" in the API to be returning something related to what I am looking for (but it only provides very limited details, and no way to set custom dates) 
API I request used :  https://developers.crittercism.com:443/v1.0/apps?attributes=appName,crashPercent,mau,rating

Am I missing something in the documentations??

Can someone tell me how I can get the details I want from via the Rest API??

Mainly the crash trends details like AVAILABILITY/CRASH PERCENT/DAU/MAU etc., for custom date intervals (not exceeding more than a month). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a product manager at Crittercism.
The developers.crittercism.com/v1.0/apps endpoint gives you a snapshot of the app data along with some other properties ( link to the apps tore, icon url etc)
For your requirement you should use this endpoint
developers.crittercism.com/v1.0/errorMonitoring/graph 
You use this to get retrieve the following metrics

- dau
- mau
- rating
- crashes
- crashPercen
- appLoads
- affectedUsers
- affectedUserPercent

You can query for two time ranges 1 day (1440 mins) and 1 month (43200 mins)
Here is the documentation for this http://docs.crittercism.com/api/api.html#!/errorMonitoring/graph
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the errormonitoring endpoint in the API. But is there a posibiility to define our custom date ranges, instead of just choosing the past 1 day or 1 month ?? Thanks

Comment: Currently there is no support for this. But this is on the roadmap.